# Project Euler 28 - Number Spiral Diagonals

Tags: python, programming-challenge

[Project Euler problem 28](http://projecteuler.net/problem=28)

> Starting with the number 1 and moving to the right in a clockwise direction a 5 by 5 spiral is formed as follows:
>
> $$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
> \color{red}{21} &22 &23 &24 &\color{red}{25}\\
> 20 & \color{red}{7} & 8 & \color{red}{9} &10\\
> 19 & 6 & \color{red}{1} & 2 &11\\
> 18 & \color{red}{5} & 4 & \color{red}{3} &12\\
> \color{red}{17} &16 &15 &14 &\color{red}{13}\\
> \end{array}$$
>
> It can be verified that the sum of the numbers on the diagonals is 101.
>
> What is the sum of the numbers on the diagonals in a 1001 by 1001 spiral formed in the same way?

I realized that the spiral was essentially an arithmetic sequence, so I based my code off of that.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()

def spiral_diag_sum(n):
    if n < 1: return None
    elif n == 1: return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0: return None
    else:
        numbers = [1]
        while len(numbers) < (2*n - 1):
            increment = int(len(numbers) * 0.5 + 1.5)
            for p in range(4):
                numbers.append(numbers[-1] + increment)     
    return sum(numbers)

ans = spiral_diag_sum(1001)
elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 1000 # s --> ms
print "Found %d in %r ms." % (ans, elapsed_time)
```

Comment: Metric Marvin says, "1s = 1000ms." :)

Answer (score 7):

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
```

This line of code belongs with the code at the end of the program that times the call to `spiral_diag_sum`.

```
def spiral_diag_sum(n):
```

It's always a good idea to add a docstring. Several of the later Project Euler problems rely on finding a solution to earlier ones (though perhaps not this one), so you'll find yourself building up a library of useful code to reuse, in which case a good docstring makes it much easier to import.

```
    if n < 1: return None
    elif n == 1: return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0: return None
    else:
```

Checking that your arguments are sane is good. However, here you've got (in sequence) an error condition, a successful return, an error condition and (following the `else`) the main body of the function. It's better to separate the error conditions and handle them first.

You're also returning `None` as the error value, but you're not checking for that value after you call `spiral_diag_sum` at the end of the program. Add code to check that, or better yet, raise an exception here indicating the error. Since both the `n < 1` and `n % 2 == 0` clauses are checking the same argument's validity, you can combine them into one if-statement:

```
    if n < 1 or n % 2 == 0: 
        raise ValueError("argument must be an odd-valued integer >= 1")
```

Resuming with the `if n == 1: return 1` from the original code:

```
    if n == 1: 
        return 1
```

Even when it's a short piece of code like here, I like to keep separate statements on their own line. Most Python code that you see will do that.

```
    else:
        numbers = [1]
        while len(numbers) < (2*n - 1):
            increment = int(len(numbers) * 0.5 + 1.5)
            for p in range(4):
                numbers.append(numbers[-1] + increment)     
        return sum(numbers)
```

The formulas here need more thought than is required. Calculate and store the `(2*n -1)` formula in a variable with a descriptive name. The `increment` starts at 2 for the first row out from the center, and goes up by two for every subsequent row, so this whole thing could be:

```
        numbers_needed = 2 * n - 1
        increment = 2
        while len(numbers) < numbers_needed:
            for p in range(4):
                numbers.append(numbers[-1] + increment)     
            increment += 2
    return sum(numbers)
```

This [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47062/40421) already explains about the downsides of using a list to hold all the numbers and shows how to calculate the number at each corner. You can go even further and derive a mathematical formula for the total contributed by the four corners of an NxN square, then use that formula iterating from the central 1x1 square out to the final NxN.

> Hint: the last corner of an NxN square will have the value N<sup>2</sup>. The values of the other three corners can be derived from that value. The same formula also works for the central 1x1 square so you don't even need to have a special case for it.

```
ans = spiral_diag_sum(1001)
elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 100 # s --> ms
print "Found %d in %r ms." % (ans, elapsed_time)
```

Following from some things I mentioned earlier: making this into a module that you can use in later problems, checking for a valid return value from `spiral_diag_sum`, and keeping all the timing code together:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":       # Allows standalone use or as a library module.
    start = timer()              # This code moved from above.
    ans = spiral_diag_sum(2)
    elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 100 # s --> ms
    if ans:                      # Check for valid answer (or use try / except)
        print "Found %d in %r ms." % (ans, elapsed_time)
    else:
        print "No answer returned"
```

Answer (score 6):

Accumulating all the numbers in a list is unnecessary, and with large numbers you might reach the memory limit. This is equivalent and more efficient:

```
count = 1
lastnum = 1
total = lastnum
while count < (2 * n - 1):
    increment = count * 0.5 + 1.5
    for p in range(4):
        lastnum += increment
        total += lastnum
        count += 1
return total
```

This has the added benefit that the result is already summed, no need to run `sum(...)` on a potentially large list.

I dropped an unnecessary cast in `int(count * 0.5 + 1.5)`. This gives a noticeable improvement in `elapsed_time`.

In your original code, you misplaced the indent of `return sum(numbers)`: it is outside of the `else` block, so it's a bit dirty.

This may be a matter of taste, but I like to flatten this kind of if-else code like this:

```
if n < 1:
    return None
if n == 1:
    return 1
if n % 2 == 0:
    return None
....
```

In any case, [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends to break the line after `:`. It's good to run `pep8` and `pyflakes` on your code and follow the recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the special cases in the beginning are a bit clumsy:

```
def spiral_diag_sum(n):
    if n < 1: return None
    elif n == 1: return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0: return None
    else:
        # Build the numbers list here
        …
    return sum(numbers)
```

Those cases are there for validation; they shouldn't look like a part of the calculation.  Furthermore, *n* = 1 does not need to be a special case, so you shouldn't write it as such.

```
def spiral_diag_sum(n):
    if n < 1 or n % 2 == 0:
        raise ValueError(n)

    numbers = [1]
    …
```

---

I don't like this foray into floating point:

```
increment = int(len(numbers) * 0.5 + 1.5)
```

$$
increment =
\left\lfloor \frac{\mathrm{len}(numbers)}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \right\rfloor =
\left\lfloor \frac{\mathrm{len}(numbers) + 3}{2} \right\rfloor
$$

That should be written in Python as

```
increment = (len(numbers) + 3) // 2
```

But, as @NiallC points out, it suffices to write

```
increment += 2
```

since `len(numbers)` increases by 4 each time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a list or nested loops in this algorithm.

Here is how I solved by making use of the pattern exhibited in the description:

- `corner1=i**2` (NE corner, where `i` is the height/width dimension of each concentric square)
- `corner2=corner1-(i-1)` (NW corner)
- `corner3=corner2-(i-1)` (SW corner)
- `corner4=corner3-(i-1)` (SE corner)

```
def problem28():
    total=1
    for i in xrange(3,1002,2):
        total+=i**2 + (i**2-(i-1)) + (i**2-2*(i-1)) + (i**2-3*(i-1))
    return total
```